# How to create different db configurations on a single Redis instance

Tags: redis

I'm using Redis as a caching system on the client windows endpoint. I want to use two simultaneous caching streams where one is lru enabled and the other is disabled.
How do I run two different configs on the same instance?

Ended up using two instances with aof

Comment: not a programming question per se.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK so talked to people at Redis. It's not possible as all the configuration is global for the instance.
So the only solution is to have two different instances